# get list of files in directory that are 3 extensions and only numbers

Tags: c#, getfiles

I am using this code:

```
  var list = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _globalSetting.CompanyCode + "trn*.???", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

  foreach (var listitem in list)
  {
    listBox_Files.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(listitem));
  }
```

but it's giving me more than I need. I'd like it to only give me files with 3 extensions, and if I could, only those with numbers in them.  I tried the ??? above but it's giving me this:

```
WEBTRN25.000
WEBTRN25.001
WEBTRN25.000_copy
WEBTRN34.ABC
```

I also tried ### but that gave me no results.

This is what I would like it to give back:

```
WEBTRN25.000
WEBTRN25.001
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not possible using the simple `searchPattern` argument. You could write a quick RegularExpression for this tho. Something like this: `/^.+\.[0-9]{3}$/`

Comment: +1 @Diamondo25 [Search Pattern Wildcards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx#remarksToggle) Try getting all files, then filter using linq and a Regex expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine a Regex expression with a Linq clause Where

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^\.\d\d\d$");
var list = Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                               _globalSetting.CompanyCode + "trn*.*", 
                               SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                               .Where(x => r.IsMatch(Path.GetExtension(x)));
```

Notice that I have replaced your call to GetFiles with EnumerateFiles. This method allows to start the enumeration of the collection before the whole directory list has been read. So, EnumerateFiles (if you have many files in the directory) could be more efficient.

Comment: This still gave me the WEBTRN25.000_copy but I checked the length of the extension with `Path.GetExtension(listitem).Length == 4` and the combination worked.

Comment: Please, refresh the answer, I have updated the pattern for the RegEx. The original patters doesn't consider the point in front of the extension returned by GetExtension()

Answer (score 0):

you could use a regex to make sure the file name ends in [dot then three numbers]

```
.*\\.[0-9]{3}$
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try using LINQ:

`var list = Directory.GetFiles("<DIRECTORY>").Where(a=> Regex.IsMatch(a, @"\d\d\d")).ToList().Foreach((b)=> Path.GetFileName(b));`. You wouldnt need the foreach loop